Chain customers into clusters based on common field
I have a customer_master and a customer_details table.
I want to retrieve a cluster of customers, connected by legal_identifier.
For example, customer C1 has legal identifier L1.
L1 is also the legal identifier for C2, which in turn has 1 more legal identifier L2.
L2 is also the legal identifier for C3, which has 2 more legal identifiers: L3 and L4.
L3 is also assigned to C5.
L4 is also assigned to C4, which has 1 more legal identifier L1.
So, all these customers from C1 to C5 are a cluster, because they have some common legal identifier.
C6 has a legal identifier L6, so it is not part of the C1-C5 cluster. C6 will be a separate cluster, which has only C6, but would have more customers if they were connected by some common legal identifier.
I want to show 1 row for each cluster.
I need output in the form of: cust_ids (comma separated list of the customer_master.id which belong to the same cluster).
I am okay to use temporary tables if they cannot be avoided with the limitations of MySQL, and if that makes the code more readable and maintainable.
I am looking for a linked-list kind of cluster; not sure if there is a specific problem name for what I am trying to solve.
Basically, I want to traverse the entire list of customers for each legal identifier and the tree can be any level deep.
As soon as we find that all legal identifiers of a customer are not assigned to any other customer, that is the end of the cluster.
CREATE TABLE customer_master (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE customer_details (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cust_id INT,
    legal_identifier VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES customer_master(id)
);


INSERT INTO customer_master(id, name)
    VALUES (1, 'C1'), (2, 'C2'), (3, 'C3'), (4, 'C4'), (5, 'C5'), (6, 'C6');
    
INSERT INTO customer_details(id, cust_id, legal_identifier)
    VALUES 
    (1, 1, 'L1'),
    (2, 2, 'L1'),
    (3, 2, 'L2'),
    (4, 3, 'L2'),
    (5, 3, 'L3'),
    (6, 3, 'L4'),
    (7, 4, 'L4'),
    (8, 5, 'L3'),
    (9, 6, 'L6'),
    (10, 4, 'L1');

EDIT 1:
I tried the following recursive CTE:
Note: This works only after deleting the 10th record:
DELETE FROM customer_details WHERE id = 10;
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS 
(
SELECT cm1.id, cm1.`name`, cd1.legal_identifier, -1 AS 'connected_id', 1 AS recursion_level
FROM customer_master cm1
INNER JOIN customer_details cd1 ON cm1.id = cd1.cust_id

UNION ALL

SELECT cte1.id, cte1.`name`, cte1.legal_identifier, cm2.id AS 'connected_id', cte1.recursion_level + 1
FROM cte1
INNER JOIN customer_details cd2 ON cte1.legal_identifier = cd2.legal_identifier 
INNER JOIN customer_master cm2 ON cm2.id = cd2.cust_id AND cm2.id != cte1.id AND cm2.id NOT IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cte1.connected_id))
)
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(connected_id) AS 'cluster' FROM cte1 WHERE connected_id != -1 GROUP BY legal_identifier
UNION
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM cte1 WHERE connected_id = -1 GROUP BY legal_identifier
;

But it includes only the immediate customer record with the same legal identifier. It generates 5 rows:
cluster
========
1,2
2,3
3,5
3,4
6

But the required output is:
cluster
========
1,2,3,4,5
6

EDIT 2:
I am open to make any changes in database design to support the required output. But the insertion, deletion and updation of records should be smooth too.

Really? The published query times out for me.

Oh ya, I checked now. In my local, I did not have the 10th record (10, 4, 'L1'), so the query runs for me and returns the 5 rows. But with the 10th record, it just displays OK in the Output Pane @P.Salmon

But the scenario shown in 10th record may also be present in the actual data. So I am looking for a solution considering that in mind. Anyway, my query output is also not what I finally wanted in the 1st place.

I don't think it possible to use recursion on non hierarchical data so something procedural with a couple of helper tables
create procedure p()
begin
declare vloop_limit int default 100;
declare viteration  int;
declare vcluster    int;
declare voffset     int default 0;
declare vmaxoffset  int;
declare vcust_id    int;
drop table if exists cd_temp;
drop table if exists cluster;    
create table cd_temp
(
    iteration int,
     legal_identifier VARCHAR(100)
);
create table cluster(id int, cust_id int);

#truncate table cd_temp;

select count(*) -1  into vmaxoffset from customer_master;
#select vmaxoffset;

masterloop:loop

if  voffset > vmaxoffset then
     leave masterloop;
end if;

select id into vcust_id from customer_master limit 1 offset voffset;

truncate table cd_temp;
set viteration = 0;

#select * from cd_temp;
label1: loop
if exists (select 1 from cluster where cluster.cust_id = vcust_id) then
    leave label1;
end if;
set viteration = viteration + 1;
if viteration = 1 then
insert into cd_temp 
select viteration, legal_identifier
from   customer_details 
where  cust_id = vcust_id
;
else
insert into cd_temp
select distinct viteration,
         #cdt.* ,
         #cd.*,
         cd1.legal_identifier
from   cd_temp cdt
join   customer_details cd on cd.legal_identifier = cdt.legal_identifier and cdt.iteration = viteration - 1
join   customer_details cd1 on cd1.cust_id = cd.cust_id and  cd1.legal_identifier <> cd.legal_identifier
where not exists (select 1 from cd_temp where cd_temp.legal_identifier = cd1.legal_identifier);
end if;

if not exists(select 1 from cd_temp where cd_temp.iteration = viteration) then 
   leave label1;
end if; 
end loop label1;

#select * from cd_temp;

set vcluster = (select coalesce(max(id),0) +1 from cluster);
insert into cluster
select distinct vcluster, cd.cust_id 
from cd_temp cdt
join customer_details cd on cd.legal_identifier = cdt.legal_identifier;

#select * from cluster;
set voffset = voffset +1;
end loop masterloop;
end ;

https://dbfiddle.uk/6CxBkAHH
